# WPF - synchronous UI update

Tags: wpf, user-interface, dispatcher, synchronous

If I understand correctly changing any control in WPF (eg. text of a Label) enqueues an update in Dispatcher. Dispatcher waits for my code to finish and when it has time it processes the whole queue.

For this, calling

```
double  current = 0;
ReportProgress (0d, "ProcessingStarted");
foreach (var item in collection)
{
        item.Process(); //takes about 10s
        current++;
        ReportProgress (current / (double)collection.Count, "Processing item No. " + current.ToString () + " finished");
}
ReportProgress (1d, "Finished");
```

where ReportProgress invokes an event with this event handler

```
private void handlerProgressMade (object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
    pbProgress.Value = pbProgress.Maximum * e.Percent;
    lbProgressMessage.Content = e.Message;
}
```

ends up with full progressbar and message "Finished" displayed, but the intersteps are not shown.

I am aware that it could be done by calling the function in different thread and updating UI asynchronously (and it is going to happen at some point), but for now adding threads seems like unnecessary complication.

How to force the Dispatcher to update and redraw immediately?

Comment: i feel like you have no other option to get it worked you have to go for threading... if there is a work around no one will go for threading.. following link may help you implementing threading http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html

Comment: @bathineni I know it can be done with threads. And it is unimportant if UI is responding, just reporting progress would be fine.

Comment: @Lukas.. may be i am wrong.. but for me reporting progress is nothing but UI Response

Comment: Dispatcher doesnt wait for your code to finish. It processes the message queue depending your priority, unless you do the "actual" work which takes longer in GUI thread

Comment: Is that a BackgroundWorker you are using, or something build around the dispatcher? Try use a BackgroundWorker then, it has a built in way of Notifying progress.

Comment: @anvarbek raupov: there is only one thread so yes, I do the actual work in the same thread where GUI is run.

Comment: @dowhilefor: No it is all in one thread, no backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use background thread, then before and after you set the progress bar value, old hack of `Application.DoEvents()` might help as it will wait to clear all message queue that got piled up in the GUI Message Bus

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents (); (does not feel right in wpf application) slows the final update down to a level where I can see all the states flash through when it is all finished, but nowhere near updating ui when I ask for it.

Comment: do u reckon this will help: http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-doevents-in-wpf.html ?